# AutocompleteText loaded from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, autocomplete

I've made an autocomplete text for a research from my database, so my SQLite create table statment is:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION =
        "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_QUESTION + "("
        + KEY_ID_QUESTION + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_PROFIL_CIBLE + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_PROFIL_WAITEDANSWER + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_REGLE + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_PLANACT + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_THEME + " TEXT"
        + ")";
```

I also created a method that returns an arraylist in my modelhelper;

```
public ArrayList getQuestionForSearch() {
    ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();
    int zise = lst.size();
    Random rand = new Random();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT  DISTINCT " + KEY_QUESTION + " from " + TABLE_QUESTION+ " where " +KEY_QUESTION+ " LIKE '%" +search+ "%'" , null);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " + KEY_QUESTION + " from " + TABLE_QUESTION, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            String t1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUESTION));
            lst.add(t1);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return lst;
}
```

In my activity, I've added an autocomplete text in my .xlm file:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/txtcomplete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Tapez votre recherche ici"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

In my .java class, I created the list and an adapter:

```
AutoCompleteTextView txt = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcomplete);

ModelHelper md = new ModelHelper(this);

String search= txt.getText().toString();
//getting list from the modelhelper
ArrayList<String> questions= md.getQuestionForSearch();
//arrayadapter
ArrayAdapter<String> myadap =   new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
//set the adapter to the autocomplete text
txt.setAdapter(myadap);
```

I verified many tutorials and it's working like that, but it's not the same for me, there is no error while compiling, while typing in the autocompletetext there is nothing happening.

Comment: what is the size for `questions`?? check `questions.size()`

Comment: nothing, I copied the code from another method and forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I found it, the problem was with the adapter, I forgot questions in the adapter line.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myadap =   new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

by

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myadap =   new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,question);
```